# Can't Load Picturebox on Form2 from User Defined Class?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

vb newbie here.. I'm trying to load an image on a picturebox on **form2** after it's called from **form1**, and the drawing statement is supposed to be in a user-defined class. Here's my codes for both **form1 and form2**:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim form2 As New Form2
    form2.Show()
  End Sub      



  Public Class Form2
  Class LoadImage
    Sub New()
        Form2.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._image
    End Sub
  End Class

  Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim li As New LoadImage
  End Sub 
End Class
```

The program can run without errors however the image doesn't show up on the pircturebox. I modified the codes and found the same problem didn't appear on form1, or if the drawing statement is not in a user-defined class...

XD it seems to be a very weird problem and my computing teacher has no idea about it. Really appreciate any help here.

Comment: On your `Form2_Load` just use the code `PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._image`. You don't need a class.

Comment: Yeah if I do so that would be fine. But I really want to figure out the reason behind it, besides I aslo get more marks if I use complex object oloriented programming rather than just some procedural languages. Any idea how to fix it?